# K means clustering not using x-axis

Tags: python, data-science, k-means

I am trying to group with k-means clustering into 3 groups.

```
df3
Entries  tmax
0   944  9.400000
1   1047 9.833333
2   1282 7.000000
3   1051 9.285714
4   697  8.571429
...
```

I am currently doing:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(df3)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(centroids)

plt.scatter(df3['tmax'], df3['Entries'], c= kmeans.labels_.astype(float), s=50, alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], c='red', s=50)
plt.show()
```

I want tmax on my x-axis and Entries on my Y. The above code appears to group the entries correctly together, however the x-axis does not display tmax values. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want `tmax` (which is in `centroids[:, 1]`) on your X, and `Entries` (which is in `centroids[:, 0]`) on Y, you need to fix this when plotting centroids:

```
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 1], centroids[:, 0], c='red', s=50)
```

Output (on some randomly generated data with similar'ish ranges):

[image: picture]